# sklearn LogisticRegression predict_proba() gives incorrect predictions when using sample_weight argument

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am trying out SciKit Learn. I thought I'd try a weighted logistic regression, but I am getting nonsense predictions from sklearn's LogisticRegression object when initialising it using the `sample_weight` argument.

Here is a toy example which demonstrates the problem. I've set up a very simple dataset, with one feature, and a binary target output.

```
feat  target  weight
A       0       1
A       0       1
A       1       1
A       1       1
B       0       1
B       0       1
B       0       1
B       1       W
```

So any sensible logistic regression should predict that when `feat=A`, there is a 0.5 probability of success. *The probability when* `feat=B` *depends on the weight* `W`:

- If `W=1`, then it looks like there is a 0.25 chance of success
- If `W=3`, this balances out the three `0`s, it looks like there is a 0.5 chance of success
- If `W=9`, there are now effectively nine `1`s and three `0`s, so a 0.75 chance of success.

A weighted logistic regression in **R** gives the right predictions:

```
test <- function(final_weight) {
  feat   <- c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B')
  target <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
  weight <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, final_weight)

  df = data.frame(feat, target, weight)

  m = glm(target ~ feat, data=df, family='binomial', weights=weight)
  predict(m, type='response')
}

test(1)
#   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8 
#0.50 0.50 0.50 0.50 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 
test(3)
#  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
#0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 
test(9)
#   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8 
#0.50 0.50 0.50 0.50 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75
```

Great. **BUT** in SciKit Learn, using the LogisticRegression object, I keep getting nonsensical predictions coming out when using `W=9`. Here is my Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from patsy import dmatrices

def test(final_weight):
    d = {
        'feat'   : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'target' : [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        'weight' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, final_weight],
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    print df, '\n'

    y, X = dmatrices('target ~ feat', df, return_type="dataframe")
    features = X.columns

    C = 1e10 # high value to prevent regularization
    solver = 'sag' # so we can use sample_weight
    lr = LogisticRegression(C=C, solver=solver)
    lr.fit(X, df.target, sample_weight=df.weight)

    print 'Predictions:', '\n', lr.predict_proba(X), '\n', '===='


test(1)
test(3)
test(9)
```

This gives the following output (I have deleted some to make it a little less verbose):

```
  feat  target  weight
...
4    B       0       1
5    B       0       1
6    B       0       1
7    B       1       1

Predictions:
[[ 0.50000091  0.49999909]
...
 [ 0.74997935  0.25002065]]
====
  feat  target  weight
...
4    B       0       1
5    B       0       1
6    B       0       1
7    B       1       3

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/sag.py:267: ConvergenceWarning: The max_iter was reached which means the coef_ did not converge
Predictions:
[[ 0.49939191  0.50060809]
...
 [ 0.49967407  0.50032593]]
====
  feat  target  weight
...
4    B       0       1
5    B       0       1
6    B       0       1
7    B       1       9

Predictions:
[[ 0.00002912  0.99997088]   # Nonsense predictions for A!
...
 [ 0.00000034  0.99999966]]  # And for B too...
====
```

You can see that when I set the final weight to 9 (which doesn't seem like an unreasonably high weight) the prediction is ruined! Not only are the predictions for `feat=B` ridiculous, but **the predictions when** `feat=A` **are also now ridiculous**.

My question is

- Why are these predictions going so wrong when the final weight is 9?

Is there something I've done wrong or misunderstood?

More generally, I'd be really interested if anyone out there has successfully used **weighted** logistic regression in SciKit Learn, and achieved similar predictions as those given by **R**'s `glm(..., family='binomial')` function.

Many many thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the problem is in the solver:

```
solver = 'sag'
```

Using a stochastic solver is common for large datasets with an iid assumption of your training examples. It does not work well with high sample weights.

After changing the solver to to `lbfgs` the results match what you are seeing in R.

```
solver = 'lbfgs'
```

Comment: David, many thanks! This seems to work perfectly. For some reason I had got it into my head that only 'sag' solver could be used with sample_weight, but that's not the case.